# DearPyGui | Обработка нажатия кнопки

Tags: python, dearpygui

Мне необходимо добавлять виджеты после нажатия кнопки в уже созданное окно, но когда после нажатия кнопки я пытаюсь сделать это в окне с тем-же тегом, почему-то создаётся новое окно.
Мой код:

```py
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg
import re

VERSION = "1.0.0"

dpg.create_context()

def colored_text(text):
    colors = re.findall("{(......)}", text)
    with dpg.group(horizontal=True, horizontal_spacing=0):
        for i, sub in enumerate(re.split("{......}", text), -1):
            if i > -1:
                r, g, b = bytes.fromhex(colors[i])
                dpg.add_text(sub, color=(r, g, b, 255))
            elif sub: dpg.add_text(sub)

def new_condition():
    with dpg.window(tag="Settings"):
        dpg.add_text("Test")

with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font("Trebucbd.ttf", 14, default_font=True, id="default"):
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)

with dpg.window(tag="Settings"):
    dpg.bind_font("default")
    colored_text("Версия: {0E9618}" + VERSION)
    enable = dpg.add_checkbox(label="Работа программы", default_value=True)
    dpg.add_text()
    dpg.add_button(label="Добавить условие", callback=new_condition)
    dpg.add_separator()

dpg.create_viewport(title='Test Settings', small_icon="icon.ico", large_icon="icon.ico", width=400, height=200, resizable=False)
dpg.setup_dearpygui()
dpg.show_viewport()
dpg.set_primary_window("Settings", True)
# while dpg.is_dearpygui_running():
#     # print(dpg.get_value(enable))
#     dpg.render_dearpygui_frame()
dpg.start_dearpygui()
dpg.destroy_context()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def new_condition():
    dpg.add_text("Test", parent="Settings")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]